# javascript - Create new <li> element with textarea onclick of button

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<li><textarea></textarea></li><br><a id="newPoints"></a>
<input type="button" value="+ Add new point" onclick="newPoint();">
```

CSS (if you need it):

```
textarea {
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 300px;
    height: 60px;
    resize: vertical;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And Javascript:

```
function newPoint() {
    var a = document.getElementById("newPoints");
    a.innerHTML += '<li><textarea placeholder="To delete this point, select this textbox and press the &quot;Delete&quot; button on your keyboard." onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 46) { this.parentNode.nextSibling.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.nextSibling); this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); }"></textarea></li><br>';
}
```

To better visualise, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5AeV/1/).

So basically, with the code above, I'm trying to make it such that when the user clicks on the button, a new `<li>` (that comes with a `<br>` after it) that contains a `<textarea>` will get created. This new `<li>`, `<textarea>` and the following `<br>` will be deleted when the user presses the <kbd>Delete</kbd> button on their keyboard while selecting the textarea.

The problem is that, when the user creates a new `<li>` and types some text into its textarea, then create another `<li>`, the text from the textarea of the previous `<li>` will disappear.

How can I fix this?

Comment: you are not using .append

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee Doesn't matter, I still have `<a id="newPoints"></a>`.

Comment: that is what I'm trying to say
`var a = document.getElementById("newPoints");`
each time I guess the id is not new, its always the same

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee So what's your point...? I tried taking this line `var a = document.getElementById("newPoints");` out of the function but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `CreateElement` and `appendChild` to add the elements. I think what is happening is when you append to the innerHTML, it is overwriting everything in `newPoints`.

```
function newPoint() {
    var a = document.getElementById("newPoints");
    var l = document.createElement("li");
    l.innerHTML = '<textarea placeholder="To delete this point, select this textbox and press the &quot;Delete&quot; button on your keyboard." onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 46) { this.parentNode.nextSibling.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.nextSibling); this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); }"></textarea>';
    var b = document.createElement("br");
    a.appendChild(l);
    a.appendChild(b);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MzENe/1/

Comment: Better yet, now no textarea is actually being created... (Based on the fiddle)

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
function newPoint() {
    var a = document.getElementById("newPoints");
    var newcontent = document.createElement('li');
    newcontent.innerHTML = "<textarea placeholder='To delete this point, select this textbox and press the &quot;Delete&quot; button on your keyboard.' onkeydown=\"if(event.keyCode == 46) {  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);}\"></textarea>";
    a.appendChild(newcontent);
}
```

Comment: The code was almost correct, I've edited it so that there won't be double `li`s